# perl DBIx sqlite {sqlite_unicode=>1}?

Tags: perl, sqlite, unicode, cjk, dbix-class

If connecting to [MySQL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3amysql) with:

```
my $schema = MyDatabase::Main->connect("dbi:mysql:database=$database;host=$host",'root','', {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1});
```

The connection is forced to utf8;

Connect to [SQLite](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBD%3a%3aSQLite):

```
my $schema = MyDatabase::Main->connect('dbi:SQLite:data/sample.db', {sqlite_unicode => 1});
```

The connection seems not to be in utf8;

The purpose is to eliminate having to use decode() while fetching data:
from:

```
Mojo::ByteStream->new($cycle->type)->decode('utf-8')
```

to:

```
$cycle->type
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What if you connect with this:

```
my $schema = MyDatabase::Main->connect(
    'dbi:SQLite:data/sample.db',
    '', # empty username
    '', # empty password
    {sqlite_unicode => 1}
);
```

Maybe `connect()` is looking for the options hash-ref as argument four without realizing that SQLite doesn't need the username and password arguments.

Comment: i almost didn't click to this thread because the subject line was unclear...but that's what made me click.  i'm glad i did, and although comments aren't typically for thank yous, i wanted to extend my thanks.  this unicode/wide character stuff is a pain and this saved me from a huge headache.